# PHP Tubepress pro with Smarty, plugin issue

Tags: php, plugins, smarty, tubepress

I need a Youtube thumbnails list with `embed`. I already got Tubepress and I'm trying to integrate it with the Smarty template from Prestashop, but something's wrong.

I have an initialized and correct variable into tpl:

```
{$searchvideo = $product->name|escape:'htmlall':'UTF-8'} 
{searchvid}
```

`$searchvideo` is the string of the product name. `searchvid` is from  `function.searchvid.php` into plugins directory of Prestashop.

`function.searchvid.php`:

```
<?php 
function smarty_function_searchvid($params, $template) { 
$tubepress_base_url = "http://domain.com/folder/tubepress_pro_2_2_9"; 
include "/home/folder/www/tubepress_pro_2_2_9/sys/classes/TubePressPro.class.php"; 
$searchvideo = $template->getTemplateVars("searchvideo"); 
print TubePressPro::getHtmlForHead(true); 
print TubePressPro::getHtmlForShortcode('mode="tag" tagValue="intitle:'. $searchvideo .'" thumbHeight="100" thumbWidth="100" embeddedHeight="325" embeddedWidth="534" embeddableOnly="true" resultsPerPage="5"'); 
} 
?>
```

The problem is, the page doesn't load anything even after I call `{searchvid}`. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a plugin function is supposed to **return** it's string, not print it. have you tried that? is that tubepress class even loading properly?